# Value in local storage replaced instead of updated

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have made this phone book site where it stores for now the name and the phone number of the user.
Now I have hit a wall where if I insert the user data (name and phone number) it pushes it to the phone book array and when I try to push another user it replaces the first one instead of updating the array.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
"use strict";
let myStorage = window.localStorage;

function showOverlay(showButton, showContainer) { // this whole funciton opens up the overlay
  const addButton = document.querySelector("." + showButton);
  addButton.addEventListener("click", function addSomthing() {
    document.querySelector("." + showContainer).style.display = 'block';
  });
}

showOverlay("addBtn", "formContainer");

function cancelOverlay(cancelButton, showContainer) { //this dynamic funciton helps with closing overlays after we are done with the event
  const removeOverlay = document.querySelector("." + cancelButton);
  removeOverlay.addEventListener("click", function removeSomthing() {
    document.querySelector("." + showContainer).style.display = 'none';
  });
}

cancelOverlay("cancelOverlay", "formContainer");

function inputAndOutput() {
  cancelOverlay("submitButton", "formContainer"); //this function helps me close the form window after i click on send
  const form = document.getElementById("addForm");

  form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => { //this is a submit event when the send button is pressed it makes an object and with the help of JSON it puts it into an array 
      let formOutput = {

        name: document.getElementById("name").value,
        phoneNumber: document.getElementById("phone").value
      } //end of form
      myStorage.setItem("formOutput", JSON.stringify(formOutput)); //array of obj
      console.log(myStorage.getItem('formOutput')); //testing
      displayOutput();
      e.preventDefault(); //prevent the page to reload

    } //end of Event
    , );
}

inputAndOutput();
let phoneArray = [100];

function displayOutput() {
  if (myStorage.getItem('formOutput')) {
    let { name, phoneNumber } = JSON.parse(myStorage.getItem('formOutput'));
    const output = document.getElementById("outPutContainer");
    phoneArray.push(output.innerHTML =
    `
    <ul>
    <li>${name} </li>
    <li>${phoneNumber} </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    `);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are setting the local store to a stringified object, where is the array you are trying to use?

Comment: _"it pushes it to the phonebook array"_ Where?

Comment: let phoneArray=[100];

Comment: `let phoneArray=[100];` doesn't push anything anywhere.

Comment: no i meant into this array , i used push in the displayOutput function

Comment: You have to push it into the array before you write the array into localStorage. Currently you are just writing the last element into localStorage. This comment `//array of obj` is wrong. It's not an array of `obj`. It's just `obj`.

Comment: Before you do `myStorage.setItem("formOutput", JSON.stringify(formOutput));` you need to read the localstorage and then parse it and then push new formOutput to it and then do setItem.

Comment: localStorage.setItem() always overwrites the value saved to that key

Comment: _"localStorage.setItem() always overwrites the value saved to that key"_ Yes, that's how localStorage works. It's a key/value store. You can store one value per key. In your case the value should be the array of `obj` not only one `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

As you are submitting the form you are just replacing the localstorage item with the new one instead of that you will have to take the value from the storage store it in a variable and then add the new values to the same variable and push that variable to the storage.
some what like this:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => { //this is a submit event when the send button is pressed it makes an object and with the help of JSON it puts it into an array 
            let formOutput = {

                name: document.getElementById("name").value,
                phoneNumber: document.getElementById("phone").value
            } //end of form


            //HERE
            const oldData = JSON.parse(myStorage.getItem("formOutput"));
            oldData.push(formOutput); // I believe its an array 
            myStorage.setItem("formOutput", JSON.stringify(oldData)); //array of obj
            console.log(myStorage.getItem('formOutput')); //testing

     
            displayOutput();
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent the page to reload


        } //end of Event
        , );
```